# Can "either" be used as an adverb, and if so does it require, allow, or prohibit the use of a comma when so used?

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, commas, adverbs, orthography

Can *either* be used as an adverb, and if so, does it always take a comma when it is? And is the following statement correct in congruence with my question? I believe there is some mistake that I don't perceive:

> He never talked to Sanena, and doesn’t like her either.

Another thing is that I feel this sentence of mine should have *either* without any comma, but somewhere in a sentence I have seen a comma placed right before the word *either*.

Could someone please clarify for me which particular conditions lead to using a comma before the word *either*?

Comment: @Araucaria 'It’s a problem I can’t solve, and I don’t think anyone else can either.' [[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/either)] is surely close enough as a given example. Coordination reduction doesn't alter things. Dictionaries _do_ a lot of grunt work in searching through corpora, so they're pretty reliable as to usage. // And the comma is totally optional; this has been covered here ad nauseam.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/either) gets perhaps even closer: 'John isn't a liar, but ... isn't exactly honest either.' ('He' deleted as per conjunction reduction). Here, though, with the contrast being emphasised by 'but', the comma is perhaps more likely: 'John isn't a liar, but isn't exactly honest, either.' The comma before 'either' (and that before the coordinator) are optional, best decided by what pauses, if any, the writer would like signalled.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth oh, sure, it's an adverb here. But dictionaries are particularly bad at adverbs and so the fact that a dictionary happens to say it is one is of no particular help.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8109 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7093 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9125 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/333904 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/361184 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236216 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/389

Answer (score 1):

***Either* can definitely be used as an adverb.  It does not always have a comma with it.** Your example sentence is grammatically correct:

> *He never talked to Sanena, and doesn't like her **either**.*

The meaning of *either* is *in addition*.  It is used in negative sentences to add emphasis.

Here is another example sentence using *either* as an adverb:

> Many hotels in Bangkok are beautiful and not expensive **either**.

(notice: no comma)

Here are two example sentences that use *either* as an adverb and a there is a comma in each sentence:

> The food in that restaurant is awful, and the tables aren't clean
>   either.
>
> I have never been there either, nor do I want to go.

Comment: Oops I couldn't clarify, OK. Can you please give an example(a sentence)  in which use of either with a comma be justified?

Comment: Read https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0004.html and note that I cannot give an authoritative answer, because there is no unique English language authority either. That is, the above answer is hardly authoritative, is it?

Comment: Hello, Patriot. Good answers on ELU should be accompanied by supporting references where reasonable; this is so that answers don't come across as mere opinion (which they sometimes are). Here, a linked reference to a sentence of the same form found in a dictionary would suffice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth   Hi, Edwin!  OK, I understand.  Can the linked reference be to something in a book that I published?

Comment: Only if you've sold a quarter as many as J K Rowling. // There's only one contributor who's allowed to self-refer on ELU. Professor J Lawler, who we're privileged to have contribute here, is a published author in linguistics. You can check his published articles and his qualifications online.

Answer (score -1):

Your sen­tence:

> He never talked to Sanena, and does not like her either.

That comma is the least of your wor­ries with this par­tic­u­lar
sen­tence.  The real prob­lem is that *and* is a ter­ri­bly
pol­y­se­mous con­junc­tion, one car­ry­ing too many pos­si­ble
mean­ings for a sin­gle punc­tu­a­tion mark alone ever to dis­am­biguate
com­pletely and safely.

First and fore­most, this *and* seems to join the two verb phrases *never
talked to Sa­nena* with *does not like her ei­ther*.  Sublim­i­nally, it
also oc­cu­pies the **gram­mat­i­cal role** of the sub­ject and thus joins
bother both sub­jects of the two re­spec­tive clauses.

Here’s a con­stituent tree of your sen­tence, cour­tesy of [the CMU
on­line link-parser
tool](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html):

```
(S (NP He)
   (VP (VP (ADVP never)
           talked
           (PP to
               (NP Sanena)))
       , and
       (VP does not
           (VP like
               (NP her)
               (ADVP either))))
   .)
```

Those sub­jects hap­pen to rep­re­sent the very same sub­ject here,
but con­ceiv­ably might be an ad­di­tional sub­ject else­where:

- He went, and John fol­lowed.
- He went and was fol­lowed by John.

This im­plic­itly binds the ob­ject as well:

- He went, and John fol­lowed, to the des­ti­na­tion.

How­ever, this func­tion­al­ity is not used when the ob­ject is
re­it­er­ated in the sec­ond clause.

More im­por­tantly, *ei­ther* can­not be used as a pred­ica­tive 
ad­verb in the sec­ond clause; that would in­stead need to be
*nei­ther* as in

- .. and nei­ther likes her.

The pref­er­ence against that leads to the sus­pi­cion that *ei­ther* might
be a sen­tence ad­verb:

- ...and ei­ther does not like her.

This ob­vi­ously sounds as if it **should** be fol­lowed by *or*:

- ...and ei­ther dis­likes her, or at least does not care.

This is se­man­ti­cally close to *but ... any­way*.

The real kicker is that *ei­ther* as a ter­mi­nal sen­tence ad­verb
might also ap­ply to the first clause to con­fer a sym­met­ric
re­la­tion. Ob­vi­ously Si­enna never talked to him, ei­ther. The
corol­lary im­plied by anal­ogy is that Si­enna does not like
him, al­though the per­spec­tive of the sen­tence does not al­low
such in­fer­ence. Rather it im­plies the ques­tion for the fact.
It would not be un­usual to fol­low up by stat­ing an asym­me­try:

- But Si­enna was se­cretly in love with him.

Another im­pli­ca­tion is that of how he could know not to like 
Si­enna. If *ei­ther* binds both clauses sym­met­ri­cally, he ei­ther
does *not yet* like her be­cause he has not had the chance, or else
he does not talk to her be­cause he does not like her. This state
of mu­tual ex­clu­sion is the pri­mary func­tion of the *ei­ther..or*
and *nei­ther..nor* dis­jun­tive con­struc­tions, which might be
the rea­son that nei­ther *too* nor *also* has been used here.

As such, it makes sense to set off the sec­ond clause with a comma,
as ad­po­si­tion, and to set off the ad­verb from the sec­ond clause.
Other­wise *ei­ther* would serve no pur­pose at all be­cause leav­ing
it out would re­tain the main con­junc­tive force rest­ing on the
word *and*.